# Can I move app from current project to another project with current data in Firebase Console of the same account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications, firebase-crash-reporting

I have a project in firebase console, this project has two apps both android.
I had only integrated Analytics, Notifications and Crashlytics.
I had thought of just deleting the app and add it afresh to the new project in firebase I have created for it but I don't know what will happen to the current users with app installed.
Is there anyway I can just migrate this app to the new project apart from deleting it and re-adding it to the new project. I have tried to google and look for a solution but all solutions direct me to migrating the app to another account not to another project in the same account.
If you have any idea or advise, help me please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same question and I reached out to the support channel, here's their response:

Transferring apps from Project A to Project B, wouldn't be possible. We don't have a way in the UI to transfer an app across projects, but it can be done manually by deleting the app in Project A and creating it again in Project B. Deleting an app does not delete the API keys or the OAuth clients associated with it. But it does mark the underlying Analytics data for deletion. If you're using Firebase Auth, you could whitelist Project B's OAuth client in Project A via the Auth UI.

However you can do the following:

1. **Realtime Database**

   > You'll have to manually export and import your data through Firebase Console or using [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data). Both options need to chunk uploads so that it will fit within the [256 MB limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits?authuser=0#reads).
2. **Firestore**

   > Exporting or importing through Firebase Console is not currently available. However, you may develop your own import/export process for your Firestore instance as an alternative by using our SDKs or REST API. You can view this [StackOveflow post](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F46746604%2Ffirestore-new-database-how-do-i-backup&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNG7lT3kgqKCwRYfzvKxMF66y0cWNA) and this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/Import$2Fexport%7Csort:date/firebase-talk/k1CQK6YH2Zs/tezz_9XxEgAJ) for more information.
3. **Cloud Storage for Firebase**

   > Since Firebase Storage is backed by Google Cloud Storage, you can use the gsutil tool. You can use the [copy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) ( cp ) or [move](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv) (mv) command.  You may also look at this ([stackoverflow answer](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F38601548%2Fhow-to-move-files-with-firebase-storage&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHulV4_sVuO8obeMzL6iOrGkiP9hA)) for the GCloud Node option.
4. **Cloud Functions for Firebase**

   > You’ll have to manually deploy your Functions code to the other projects.
5. **Authentication**

   > You could use [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth) to import and export user accounts.

Comment: Any idea how I can move the reserve .web.app hosting alias to new project?

Comment: sorry, mate. I got no idea. reaching to their support channel would be the best move I can suggest.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65927522/394010

Answer (score 4):

The Firebase console provides no way to migrate an app and all its data from one project to another.  You may want to contact [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to see if there is something special that can be done.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response, the reference link you shared just takes me to a contact us form for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 4):

1. remove your ***.firebaserc*** file and ***firebase.json*** from your project.
2. run ***firebase init***
3. select your project
4. deploy.

After deploying the new project you can remove the old one. This worked for me.